# java referencing generics in static context

Tags: java, generics

So I'm trying to do this:

```
interface Graph<E extends Edge, N extends Node>{
    List<E> edges = new ArrayList<>();
    List<N> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    void addNode();
    Node getNode(int i);
    void addEdge();
    Edge getEdge(int i);
    List<N> getNodes();
    List<E> getEdges();

}
```

On the `List<E> =...` and `List<N> = ...` I'm getting the error `mypackage.Graph.this cannot be referenced from a static context`.

Why isn't this working? How can I declare these lists of generics?

Comment: You cannot have member fields in an interface.  So these are effectively `static final` constants, so have no access to generic parameters.

Comment: Only `final static` fields are permitted in interfaces, i.e. constants

Comment: Please provide the *complete error message* and/or *stack strace* you get.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, AniketSahrawat: fields in *interfaces* are implicitly `static final`.

Comment: Java basics for the win. Start with reading the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Your comment is not correct, from the docs: *"In addition, an interface can contain constant declarations. All constant values defined in an interface are implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`. Once again, you can omit these modifiers."* As OliverCharlesworth said, the problem is the generic parameter.

Comment: >> How can I declare these lists of generics? List<? extends Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @jimboweb, please update your example code with the one that actually produces the error; that is the one that includes the ```Graph.this``` reference. It seems to me that for what you intent to do is best to change Graph to an abstract class (or declared a separate ```AbstractGraph``` that implements it) and or avoid exposing those lists directly and provide accessor methods.